# ruby activerecord multiple connection pool

Tags: ruby, activerecord, connection-pooling

Is there any good documentation or tutorial available about active record multiple connection pooling?
I am looking for the multiple database connection and need to switch the connection accordingly.

It would be highly greatful if you could get me an idea!

Comment: Do you use ActiveRecord with Rails? Could you show me an example of what you would like to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aiming to have a master-slave schema you should try [multi_db](https://github.com/schoefmax/multi_db)

Comment: I want to connect multiple databases and need to switch the connection according to the parameter passed along with the request.